# How to set reference to the folder which contains multiple jar files?

Tags: netbeans, jar, glassfish-3

**My environment:**

```
Netbean 6.9.1
Glassfish 3.0.1
Windows 7
```

**Goal:**

When my coworkers opens the Netbean Project, **the library is already referenced without them manually create library, adding jars into it and reference it.**

**Detail:**

I created `Netbean project` and the project has reference to few jar files in the folder. 
Currently whoever opens the project for the first time, they have to manually create library and refer it to the project.

**My project location:**

C:\Users\masatosan\Desktop\myProject\myApp

**My library location:**

C:\Users\masatosan\Desktop\myProject\lib\myLib

**The myLib folder contains:**

```
some1.jar
some2.jar
some3.jar
```

I can achieve my goal if I create reference to individual jar file by defining to `project.properties` file like below: (creating reference to sqljdbc4.jar)

```
file.reference.sqljdbc4.jar=../lib/sqljdbc4.jar
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.restlib_gfv3ee6.classpath}:\
    ${file.reference.sqljdbc4.jar}:
```

But my case is different since I have 3 jars in the myLib folder and wanting to reference them all.

Is it possible to reference all jars in `myLib` folder?

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: You want it to just find all jars in the folder without naming them?

Comment: Do you mean merging multiple jar file into one jar?

Comment: No, what I mean is. Do you just want to tell netbeans to scan a directory, and automatically add all the jar files it finds in the directory to the project? If that is not what you are asking, can you please explain how you are sharing your project with other users? Are you using source code control or copying files?

Comment: The former is what I'm looking for. (automatically add all the jar files it finds in the directory to the project). Specifically I want those jars already be added to the library reference of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, but it doesn't work that way. When you create a project, you have to add the jar files individually.

However, if you put your lib folder under your project, netbeans will refer to them via relative paths. Then when you share the project (lib directory included), netbeans will be able to automatically find the jar files when the next person uses the project. That way you only have to add jar files once.

Short of using a dependency management tool like maven (which Netbeans has good support for), this is really the best solution. It uses a bit more disk space (obviously), but that's never been a huge issue for me.

Comment: I've created "lib" folder under my project and put all my jars in it. I re-opened the same project and does not seem to have any effects..

Comment: Next, in the projects window (on the left), right click on the Libraries node under your project. Select "Add/JAR/Folder..." then navigate to your lib directory under your project and select a jar file. When you do this, you'll notice that the 'relative path' section becomes highlighted (you don't have to do anything with it though).  Then hit hit the "choose" button. Do the same for your other libraries. When you share the project (libraries and all), Netbeans will be able to find the jar files for the next person.

Comment: I've done that process and my question was if I could somehow skip that adding process. (like by project.properties file etc) but I guess you have answered my question already.. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I figured how so let me share.

1. Tool --> Library then library window pop up.
2. Create library called "MyLib" which contains multiple jars.
3. Add "MyLib" to your project. This change will be written to `project.properties` file under `nbproject` folder.

`project.properties` file indicates the classpath of lib reference you just added.

It should look like something below

```
javac.classpath=\
${libs.Excella.classpath}:\
${libs.MyLib.classpath}
```

Now someone else opens the project from different machine and she just needs to do step#1 and #2, which is to create library **with same library name i.e. "MyLib"**

I think this is what Bill was saying originally but thought it would be helpful to give step by step instructions since I finally figured .... after long time :D